# How to create a hash of array from input without non-empty-line separator

Tags: perl, data-structures

How can I create a hash of array from the following code and data:

This is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
while(<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my $line = $_;
  print "$line\n";
  my ($id) = /^(track.*$)/;
  my ($mem) = /^(chr22.*$)/;
  print " ID: $id - $mem\n";
  push @{$hash{$id}},$mem;
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263 
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134   
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453   
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV_8872
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440
```

So each element of has hash `track` as keys and subsequent `chr22` entries as its members.

At the end of the day I'd like to create this output:

```
$VAR = [  "track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263" => 
           ["chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134",   
            "chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453"], 
          "track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV_8872" =>
          ["chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440" ]];
```

The current execution failed: https://eval.in/89547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote in your wanted output Array brackets `[`,`]` for your hash.

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
my $track_chr = 0;
while( my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ m/^track/) {
    $track_chr = $line;
    #$hash->{$line};
  }
  if ($track_chr && $line =~ m/^chr/) {
    push @{$hash{$track_chr}},$line;
  }
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263 
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134   
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453   
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV_8872
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440
```

Pretty simple. Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263 ' => [
                                                                              'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134   ',
                                                                              'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453   '
                                                                            ],
          'track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV_8872' => [
                                                                             'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440  '
                                                                           ]
        };
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: i did :) just dont wrote it down there. but good point. i will add it :P

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1; # personal preference for readability 

my %hash;
my $key;

# iterate over a line at a time
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;

    # if the line begins with "track" store the key
    if ($line =~ /^track/) {
        $key = $line;
    } elsif ($line =~ /^chr22/) {
        # skip this line if we were not able to set a key...
        next if !defined $key;
        # else we push onto the array
        push @{$hash{$key}}, $line;
    }
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263 
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134   
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453   
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV_8872
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440 
some random line
more randomnessssssss
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ perl test.pl
$VAR1 = {
  'track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263 ' => [
    'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134   ',
    'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453   '
  ],
  'track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV_8872' => [
    'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440 '
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Perl's record separator to "track name=chr22" and read your data in those chunks:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
local $/ = 'track name=chr22';

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @items = split /\n/ or next;
    push @{ $hash{ $/ . $items[0] } }, @items[ 1 .. $#items ];
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263 
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134   
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453   
track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV
chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_29112_INS_-263 ' => [
                                                                              'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29835   30134   ',
                                                                              'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29154   29453   '
                                                                            ],
          'track name=chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]_30604_INV' => [
                                                                        'chr22[Target-Scrambled-Inversion]    29141   29440'
                                                                      ]
        };
```

Hope this helps!